# SOAP __getLastRequest outputs htmlentities encoded XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

A SOAP request that I'm making outputs htmlentities encoded XML when I call __getLastRequest after the soap request.

The __getLastRequest looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:query><ns1:sXML>
&lt;queryxml&gt;
&lt;entity&gt;UserDefinedFieldDefinition&lt;/entity&gt;
&lt;query&gt;
&lt;field&gt;id&lt;expression op="greaterthan"&gt;0&lt;/expression&gt;&lt;/field&gt;
&lt;/query&gt;
&lt;/queryxml&gt;
</ns1:sXML></ns1:query></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The strangest thing is that for the most part the SOAP request works. There are certain times where it doesn't work, so while debugging this seemingly intermittent problem I found this very strange issue regarding __getLastRequest.

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
return $this->__soapCall('query', 
        array($parameters),       
        array(
                'uri' => 'http://autotask.net/ATWS/v1_5/',
                'soapaction' => ''
        )
);
```

Parameters look like this:

```
(
    [sXML] => 

                <queryxml>
                <entity>UserDefinedFieldDefinition</entity>
                <query>
                <field>id<expression op="greaterthan">0</expression></field>
                </query>
                </queryxml>

)
```

__getLastResponse seems to return bogus xml.

I feel like __soapCall is intermittently htmlencoding the $arguments, or at the very least __getLastResponse is being erroneously encoded before it's being returned. I lean towards the latter because for the most part the requests work. Only sometimes do they not. And the request never changes from a data perspective.

Has anyone ever seen this problem before?

Thank you in advance.